# DataFrame sorting unwanted using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a basic data frame (using Pandas):

```
testDf = pandas.DataFrame({'c':[1,2],'b':[2,2],'a':[3,4]})
```

The result gives:

```
   a  b  c
0  3  2  1
1  4  2  2
```

Instead of:

```
   c  b  a
0  1  2  3
1  2  2  4
```

Why is it sorted alphabetically? I want the second result.

Comment: As others have pointed out, dicts aren't ordered.  That said, it's clearly not random that it sorts the columns alphabetically (i just tried it too), so there must be a sort by default happening.  Passing the `columns=` argument seems like the best way to get it ordered the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add parameter `columns` to [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor, because `dict` is unordered:

```
print (pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,2],'b':[2,2],'a':[3,4]}, columns=['c','b','a']))
   c  b  a
0  1  2  3
1  2  2  4
```

[`Dataframe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe):

> Along with the data, you can optionally pass **index** (row labels) and **columns** (column labels) arguments. If you pass an index and / or columns, you are guaranteeing the index and / or columns of the resulting DataFrame. Thus, a dict of Series plus a specific index will discard all data not matching up to the passed index.

Answer (score 2):

You passed a dict as the data param so the order is not the same as the order of key creation as the order is not the same, you can specify the column order by passing a list of the columns as the arg for `columns` param:

```
In [307]:
testDf = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,2],'b':[2,2],'a':[3,4]}, columns=['c','b','a'])
testDf

Out[307]:
   c  b  a
0  1  2  3
1  2  2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is unsorted, therefor you cannot expect the ordering to be the same as in the initialization.

Comment: I tried this with OrderedDict, and it doesn't seem to work either.